# I run 7 miles in around 40 mins, is this good? Any tips to improve?

Tags: running

I'm a fairly new runner and I have no idea what is a good time and what isn't. I run 3 times a week and always run 7 miles.. Can anyone give me some info on if it's good and how I can improve?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this question can help http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/8315/what-are-equivalent-swimming-and-running-speeds

Comment: Slightly faster than 6 minute miles. That would be good enough for quite a few varsity cross country teams, although not as the best runner.

Answer (score 0):

7 miles in 40 minutes is a 5:42 mile pace. Assuming you were running as fast as possible, you could probably manage a 5:37 mile pace for 10K (6.2 miles). This converts to a VDOT value of 61, so you might be able to run 16:48 for 5K. If you're 20 - 30, that would put you in the 77th percentile, meaning you're better than 77% of people aged 20 - 30 (upper regional class). If you're 30 - 40, that puts you around 77% - 80% (80% is the bottom of national class).

If you actually ran 7 miles in 40 minutes and you pick up your training (in a smart way - get advice), you could be really good.

Comment: Where are you getting the 80% percentile is national class? I'd be interested in seeing those charts.

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge. I'm 20 years old and have always been a fast runner.. I started out doing 10 minute runs a couple of months ago then just kept pushing myself. Yesterday was my fastest time so far at 39:40, when I tell people about it they don't believe me. Which is what made me want to find out how good it is.

Comment: I found percentiles here: http://www.heartbreakhill.org/age_graded.htm